# Laravel + CodeSleeve stapler bundle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using the `Codesleeve Stapler` and i have a small problem.

I did exactly what the last example described on this page:
https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler

The difference is that my new model is called Pictures instead of `ProfilePictures`
and my model is not `User` but `Trip`.

The `<img src="<?= asset($picture->photo->url('thumbnail')) ?>">`
on the view shows the last picture that has been uploaded.

I want to show the `Picture` that belongs to each `Trip`. How could i perform this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you have two models: 'Trip', and 'Picture'.  In your Trip model, you need to define a 'hasMany' relationship to the Picture model:

```
public function pictures(){
    return $this->hasMany('Picture');
}
```

Then, in your Picture model, you define the Stapler attachment:

```
// Be sure and use the stapler trait, this will not work if you don't:
use Codesleeve\Stapler\Stapler;

// In your model's constructor function, define your attachment:
public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
    // Pictures have an attached file (we'll call it image, but you can name it whatever you like).
    $this->hasAttachedFile('image', [
        'styles' => [
            'thumbnail' => '100x100#',
            'foo' => '75x75',
            'bar' => '50x50'
        ]
    ]);

    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Now that you've defined the attachment on the Picture model, every time you access a Picture object, you'll also have access to the file attachment.  Assuming you had a Trip record, you could do this:

```
<?php foreach ($trip->pictures as $picture): ?>
    <img src="<?= asset($picture->image->url('thumbnail')) ?>">
<?php endforeach ?>
```

You could access the original image like this:

```
<img src="<?= asset($picture->image->url()) ?>">
// or
<img src="<?= asset($picture->image->url('original')) ?>">
```

In fact, you can access any of the style you defined:

```
<img src="<?= asset($picture->image->url('foo')) ?>">
<img src="<?= asset($picture->image->url('bar')) ?>">
```

Hope this helps.